# Accessing Controls of a DataTemplate with underlying ContentView hosting the Controls?

Tags: maui, datatemplate

I use a SharpNado CollectionView in .NET MAUI with a DataTemplate as can be seen below.

There is also a Button which has its Button_Clicked-Event in the Code-Behind file.
From there, I wanted to evaluate each MinEntry and MaxEntry that is displayed in CollectionView. There should be an evaluation like MinEntry-Value should always greater or equal to MaxEntry-Value, also that there are values entered at all.

My current problem is, how I could access the list of all MinEntrys and MaxEntrys? Currently, I am not able to get these Controls at all. I tried several ways with FindByName etc., but I always got "null" as the FindByName-Result.

How could I access and evaluate these Controls?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:sho="http://sharpnado.com"             
             x:DataType="viewModels:MyViewViewModel"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Views.MyView">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="VerticalItemTemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type models:MySelection}">
                <sho:DraggableViewCell x:Name="DraggableViewCell">
                    <ContentView x:Name="DraggableContentView">
                       <SwipeView>

                            <Frame HeightRequest="60" Padding="15, 5, 15, 0">
                                <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="120, Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto, 70, Auto">
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

                                    <Entry Grid.Column="1" Placeholder="0" Text="{Binding Min, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" x:Name="MinEntry"/>
                                    
                                    <Entry Grid.Column="3" Placeholder="100" Text="{Binding Max, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"  x:Name="MaxEntry"/>
                                    
                                    <Label Grid.Column="5" Text="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>                             
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                            
                            ...
                        </SwipeView>
                    </ContentView>
                </sho:DraggableViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView>
    
    <StackLayout>
            
        <sho:CollectionView x:Name="CollectionView"
                            CollectionPadding="10,10,10,10"
                            CurrentIndex="{Binding CurrentIndex}"
                            EnableDragAndDrop="True"
                            DragAndDropDirection="VerticalOnly"
                            DragAndDropTrigger="LongTap"
                            ItemHeight="60"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VerticalItemTemplate}"
                            CollectionLayout="Vertical" />
        
    </StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```

Comment: You don't.  You can't and shouldn't try to directly manipulate the UI of elements in a templated control.  Instead you should validate the **data** that the control is bound to.

Comment: Well, yes you are right to a certain point and it would be possible to analyze the bound content. But, what if I want to give feedback to the user, let's say, I want to focus the corresponding Entry with the error after Displaying an Alert or directly tell the user which of the MinEntry/MaxEntry-Pairs has the error? Or maybe I want to show with a red text in the Entry which one is not allowed. When I have a couple of Entry in a list it would be strange to just show an Alert that Max value cannot be smaller than Min value or something like that - That's my problem here

Comment: Then use a behavior to add validation directly to the entry.  Or add properties to your model so you can display error messages on each individual row

Comment: The validation must be on 2 controls. I only know of validators for a specific Entry. Is there a way to validate a pair of controls like the Min and Max Entry?

Comment: When I need the combination of the Min and Max Entry to validate against each other and see if Max is always greater then the Min value, would it be a feasible solution to create the parent of these two Entry’s as an own control and register it in the ViewModel when it is created. Then when Inputs need to be evaluated after Button-Click just get the registered instance of this Custom Parent Control and then use the FindByName or other method to get its children (actually the Entrys) and evaluate them with their combination and focus on the erroneous Entry? What do you think about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My current problem is, how I could access the list of all MinEntrys
> and MaxEntrys? Currently, I am not able to get these Controls at all.
> I tried several ways with FindByName etc., but I always got "null" as
> the FindByName-Result.

We usually use [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm?view=net-maui-7.0) to achieve this.

We can add two fields (e.g. `MinValue` and `MaxValue`) to the Item model and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` .While changing the value of the two fields in the UI, the background value (`MinValue` and `MaxValue`) will also change.

I have created a demo based on the `CollectionView` on maui.

You can refer to the following code:

1.create item model `ItemModel.cs`

```
public class ItemModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //public int MinValue { get; set; }
    private int minValue;
    public int MinValue
    {
        get => minValue;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref minValue, value);
        }
    }


    //public int MaxValue { get; set; }
    private int maxValue;
    public int MaxValue
    {
        get => maxValue;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref maxValue, value);
        }
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

2.create a ViewModel `MyViewModel.cs`

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ICommand GetResultCommand { get; set; }


    public MyViewModel()
    {

        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();

        Items.Add(new ItemModel { Name = "test1", Description = "Description 1" });
        Items.Add(new ItemModel { Name = "test2", Description = "Description 2" });
        Items.Add(new ItemModel { Name = "test3", Description = "Description 3" });

        GetResultCommand = new Command(GetResult);

    }

    private void GetResult()
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("--->The result is: " + item.Name+ "Min Value = " + item.MinValue +" <--> MaxValue = " + item.MaxValue);
        }
    }
}
```

3.Usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiMvvmApp226.CollectionViewPage"
             xmlns:MauiMvvmApp="clr-namespace:MauiMvvmApp226"
             Title="CollectionViewPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <MauiMvvmApp:MyViewModel></MauiMvvmApp:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="personTemplate">
                    <HorizontalStackLayout  >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Title" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <Label Text="Min:" Margin="10,0,10,0"></Label>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding MinValue}"   WidthRequest="60"></Entry>
                            
                        <Label Text="Max:" Margin="10,0,10,0"></Label>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding MaxValue}"  WidthRequest="60"></Entry>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        
        <Button  Text="Result" Command="{Binding GetResultCommand}"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="10"/>
        
        <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource personTemplate}" x:Name="mCollectionView" >
        </CollectionView>

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Basically this is good and I would have done that in my model, too. 

But, my problem was, that I wanted to give feedback to the user in some way. A first approach could be to just set the TextColor to Red in case a MinValue > MaxValue (which is not allowed). Another approach would be to give feedback via DisplayAlert-Message that "Min value greater than Max value is not allowed" and mark the corresponding Entrys (Min-Entry as well as Max-Entry) Red. Additionally, I wanted to set the Focus to the first Entry-Pair which has an error. By checking the values in the Model, I miss the Entrys

Comment: One thread, one problem.  My answer is for the current problem(`Accessing Controls of a DataTemplate with underlying ContentView hosting the Controls?`).  For the new problem, you can create a new thread and share the link here. We are all willing to help you. :)